# Not able to get placeholder values in spring cloud config local application.properties file from kubernetes secrets and configMap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, spring-cloud-config, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I have uploaded server.path value into kubernetes configmap and db.name and db.password in kubernetes secret. These values are available in service container when I check by env command and also like 'echo $server_path'. Now I am trying to bind these values into same spring-cloud-config-server based service related application-dev.properties file. I am using placeholder like server.path=${server_path}, db.name=${db_name}

This is not working and I am getting exact key and placeholder name in postman response instead of key and placeholder value that should come from ConfigMap and Secrets.

I am New to this.

Please help.

I tried all the ways of binding k8s configMap and Secrets env values to application properties file by using ${placeholder}. Its not working. I am New to this. Please Help.

For Testing purpose, I have one key-value pair to configMap. Its jcsmp_PUB_ACK_WINDOW_SIZE : "50"
[image]

Here is my configMap yaml for same.

[image]

Here is my deployment.yaml to bind the configmap to service.
[image]

Also the value is updated in container.
[image]

Comment: If Possible can you update the question with configmap yaml along with the yaml where you are binding the configmap?

Comment: Hi @DharaniDharGolladasari I have uploaded all the details. Do you see anything that I cd try.

Comment: Everything seems fine, If you are using the same pattern for the actual deployment as you mentioned in the question then it needs to work. The other way is you can try to assign each variable by configMapKeyRef and secretKeyRef keys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning configmap and secrets to environment variables using **RefKeys** as shown below

```
template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: my-app
  spec:
   containers:
    - name: my-app
      image: nginx
      env:
       - name: myvalue
         valueFrom:
           configMapKeyRef:
             name: my-config          # Configmap name
             key: my-property
       - name: my_password
         valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: my-secret         #Secret name 
            key: password
```

The other way is you can mount configmap and secrets as **volumes**. So that these configs will mount into the Pod. You can use the **mountpath** and access these configs inside the container as follows

```
template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: my-app
  spec:
   containers:
    - name: my-app
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
       - name: config-volume
         moutnPath: /config
       - name: secret-volume
         mountPath: /secrets
   volumes:
     - name: config-volume
       configMap:
        name: my-config         #Configmap name
     - name: secret-volume
       secret:
        secretName: my-secret   #Secret name
```

Comment: Hi @Abhishek did you get a chance to look into this answer? is it helpful?

Comment: I tried the suggested approach. Facing same issue. Also I got multiple property values that too environment specific. ie. there are around 300 properties values that I need to bind with application.properties. Another important point that I want to mention is, my config service is made on top of spring.cloud.config.server that I believe returns the properties file from specific path as it is. This is tha problem. No data binding happens between properties file and configmap/secrets.